# Android / Java Algorithm to pick out pieces of String

Tags: java, android, string, algorithm

I'm writing a Chatting Application. Right now I'm trying to save Messages of each conversation. If the user reopens the specific activity, I want the app the load the messages he has already sent.

My Problem right now is following:

I'm saving the conversation data in a String like this:

> SEND#Hey youRECEIVE#Hi how are you?SEND#I´m fine and you?RECEIVE#=) so am I...

and so on. You get the concept.

Is there any way to pick out the pieces of message between the, what I call "dividers" SEND# and RECEIVE#, without having to use tons of if cases? this is my code right now:

```
if(conversation != null){
            while(conversation.contains("SEND123")|| conversation.contains("RECEIVE123")){

                if(conversation.startsWith("SEND123")){
                    String rest = conversation.substring(7);
                    System.out.println("erste if: send: " + rest);

                    if(rest.contains("SEND123") && rest.contains("RECEIVE123")){
                        if(rest.indexOf("SEND123")<rest.indexOf("RECEIVE123")){
                            String messageReady = rest.substring(0, rest.indexOf("SEND123"));   
                            conversation = rest.substring(rest.indexOf("SEND123"));
                            System.out.println(messageReady);

                        }

                        if(rest.indexOf("RECEIVE123")<rest.indexOf("SEND123")){
                            String messageReady = rest.substring(0, rest.indexOf("RECEIVE123"));    
                            conversation = rest.substring(rest.indexOf("RECEIVE123"));
                            System.out.println(messageReady);
                        }

                    }else{
                        if(rest.contains("SEND123")){
                            String messageReady = rest.substring(0, rest.indexOf("SEND123"));
                            conversation = rest.substring(rest.indexOf("SEND123"));
                            System.out.println(messageReady);
                        }
                        if(rest.contains("RECEIVE123")){
                            String messageReady = rest.substring(0, rest.indexOf("RECEIVE123"));
                            conversation = rest.substring(rest.indexOf("RECEIVE123"));
                            System.out.println(messageReady);
                            System.out.println("if contains receive: " + conversation);
                        }
                        if(!rest.contains("SEND123") || !rest.contains("RECEIVE123")){
                            conversation = rest;
                            String messageReady = rest;
                            System.out.println(messageReady);
                        }
                    }

                }
                if(conversation.startsWith("RECEIVE123")){
                    String rest = conversation.substring(10);
                    System.out.println("erste if: receive: " + rest);

                    if(rest.contains("SEND123") && rest.contains("RECEIVE123")){
                        if(rest.indexOf("SEND123")<rest.indexOf("RECEIVE123")){
                            String messageReady = rest.substring(0, rest.indexOf("SEND123"));   
                            conversation = rest.substring(rest.indexOf("SEND123"));
                            System.out.println(messageReady);

                        }

                        if(rest.indexOf("RECEIVE123")<rest.indexOf("SEND123")){
                            String messageReady = rest.substring(0, rest.indexOf("RECEIVE123"));    
                            conversation = rest.substring(rest.indexOf("RECEIVE123"));
                            System.out.println(messageReady);
                        }
                    }else{
                        if(rest.contains("SEND123")){
                            String messageReady = rest.substring(0, rest.indexOf("SEND123"));
                            conversation = rest.substring(rest.indexOf("SEND123"));
                            System.out.println(messageReady);
                        }
                        if(rest.contains("RECEIVE123")){
                            String messageReady = rest.substring(0, rest.indexOf("RECEIVE123"));
                            conversation = rest.substring(rest.indexOf("RECEIVE123"));
                            System.out.println(messageReady);
                        }
                        if(!rest.contains("SEND123") || !rest.contains("RECEIVE123")){
                            conversation = rest;
                            String messageReady = rest;
                            System.out.println(messageReady);
                        }

                    }


                    }
                }
            }
```

I'm not fully done with it. I just wanted to show you  what it looks like. This must take massive amounts of runtime. Is there any easier way to separate messages that the user got from messages he sent, but keep them in the right order?

Maybe I have to approach this problem with a different way. Maybe saving each conversation in a string is not the best idea. I bet you can help me or give me some tips.

Comment: [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)?

Comment: Doing this the way you do it is a lot more difficult than it has to be. I would recommend to use a SQLite database to save the information. You can find some general information [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db).

Comment: Is it possible to change your flags SEND/RECEIVE? In that case it would be a lot easier.

Comment: I took flags i thought the user would most likely not type during a conversation. 
What flags would you suggest?

Comment: Never try to guess what the user would not do.  They will do it ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a small SQLite database would be easier to manage. You could have the following columns:

- `sequence_num`, an auto-incrementing integer that uniquely identifies each message
- `remote_id`, an identifier for the remote partner
- `direction`, a boolean flag to indicate send vs receive
- `message`, the text of the message

You'd also probably want:

- `timestmp`, the time the message was sent/received
- `conversation_id`, an auto-incrementing integer that uniquely identifies each conversation (as defined by you)

and any other data that you'd want to track for the messages. You'd also probably want to add other tables to keep the associated connection data for each `remote_id`, etc.

### Edit:

Here's an [official link to using SQLlite on Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)  and here is a [fairly complete tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/).

Comment: i dont really understand how sqlite works. could i then save "message instances" ?

Comment: There *is* a learning curve to using SQLite, but the time spent learning it will be less than the time spent implementing your own storage protocol.

Comment: but i think im going to work my way into that. looks like it has alot advantages. saving the specific time for example is another one i just came up with

Comment: I agree in using a database to store your messages.  It will be faster/easier/provide a valuable learning experience!  I say mix up what this user said a bit and have a `message_to` and a `message_from`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a database as other suggested, this cloud be one solution.

```
String history = #SEPARATORHey you#SEPARATORHi how are you?#SEPARATORI´m fine and you?#SEPARATORGood thx#SEPARATOR;

If you do this you could use split like this:

String[] arrayHistory = history.split("#SEPARATOR"); // array now looks like this: [Hey you][Hi how are you?][I'm fine and you?][Good thx]...[send][rec][send][rec]...
```

Now you can just append the array to the textfield with the conversation in.

Comment: the problem is in a conversation there is no logic repeating of send receive send receive. it could be that the one user talks all the time while the other one rarely says anything

Comment: That is true. A quick fix is to only append the separator if the last person spoken isn't the same. Although you might be better of changing your structure of saving chat history.